# Merging two 2-d arrays in order of axes

Tags: array

Looking to merge two different 2D arrays of different row sizes into one long array:

```
 int 2dArray1[][] = {
   {1, 2, 3},
   {4, 5, 6}};
 int 2dArray2[][] = {
   {10, 20},
   {30, 40}};
 int 1dLongArray[10];
```

This is where I need help in order to have the values of 1dLongarray be arranged as follows:

```
1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 4, 5, 6, 30, 40
```

How would I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: step by step, how did you do it on paper? ... the program would do it the same way

Comment: The only way that I could think to make it work on paper would be to use memcpy for a one dimensional arrays and then create a two dimensional array out of it somehow. I'm not really sure how to do that, and I'm fairly new to coding and don't have a tutor or instructor to help me. I always try to do my best to find an answer myself before asking online but this one had me stumped.

Comment: when i say on paper, i mean, how would you do it if you knew nothing about programming ... what sequence of steps would you follow? ... i also do not mean `write down first three numbers` ... i mean baby steps, like `look at array1, row1, position1.  copy content to first empty position at destination`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using loops of length specific to the desired number of transactions.  For example, using this pseudo code create a sketch which follows this pattern:

```
initialize i to zero
loop 2 times for each row using the variable x
  loop 3 times for each element in first array using the variable y
    long array [i] = first array[x][y] 
    increment i
  loop 2 times for each element in a second array using the variable z
    long array [i] = second array[x][z]
    increment i
```

Comment: Being a brand new account I can't upvote your comment yet, so I'm leaving this comment to thank you!

Comment: If you can derive a working solution from this answer, you should be able to accept this answer as a solution to your question.

Comment: Thanks @Hitachii for making the answer as correct.  If the answer works great!  If not, please leave a comment and I'll edit the answer to improve it.

Comment: Sure. If someone were to plug the guideline for the formula that you posted, into the problem that I posted, for "long array [i] = first array [y] [x]" and "long array [i] = second array [z][x], they would have to switch the placement of x and z/y in their respective line to look like "long array [i] = first array [x][y]" to follow the original sequence of the array.

Do I post my working code? This shows how green I am to this platform.

Comment: You are correct.  The 1st argument is the row and the second is the column.  I'll change my answer.